# PHP: Limit execution time per function

Tags: php

```
foreach ($arr as $k => $v)
{
    $r = my_func($v);   

    $new[$k] = $r;
}
```

How do you do it so that `$r` will return false if `my_func()` takes more than 10 secs to execute, else (if it took less than 10 secs) it will return true;

Additional info: `my_func()` actually reads a URL, sometimes it takes to long. I want it to return false if it takes more than 10 secs.

Comment: start timer, check timer

Comment: sounds like you should be editing my_func()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot limit execution time by function in PHP. However, do not despair: if as you mentioned your function reads URL, you could use [curl](http://php.net/curl) extension, which has options set options via [curl_setopt](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php), as following:

CURLOPT_TIMEOUT  The maximum number of seconds to allow cURL functions to execute.
CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT   The number of seconds to wait while trying to connect.

Using these you could limit the actual time spent on the URL processing with curl.

You could also use [http](http://php.net/http) extension which also allows you to do http connections and has [timeout options](http://us.php.net/manual/en/http.request.options.php).

Finally, you could use [context options](https://www.php.net/manual/en/context.http.php) to [file_get_contents](http://php.net/file_get_contents):

```
$opts = array('http' =>
    array(
        'timeout' => 1.5 // 1.5 seconds
    )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);

$result = file_get_contents('http://example.com/getdata.php', false, $context);
```

Answer (score 2):

If `my_func` reads a URL and you just don't want it to take longer than a given timeout period, if you use the right URL functions, you should be able to specify that timeout and have the call fail if it takes longer than that.

If you were using cURL, you could use [curl_multi_exec](http://php.net/curl_multi_exec) to get this behavior somewhat manually, or just specify the timeout and then the function can return false.

Example:

```
function my_func($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10); // timeout after 10 seconds

    // .. set other options as needed
    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    if ($result === false) {
        // timeout or other failure
        return false;
    }
}
```

Now the function won't run longer than roughly 10 seconds due to the timeout.  You can also use [curl_errno()](http://php.net/curl_errno) to check for a timeout:

```
if (curl_errno($ch) == 28) {
    // timeout was exceeded
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do something like:

```
foreach ($arr as $k => $v)
{
    $before = time()

    $r = my_func($v); 

    $after = time();

    $timeDelta = $after - $before;
    if($timeDelta < 10){
      $r = true;
    }
    $new[$k] = $r;
}
```

Comment: Will `$after = time()` get executed even `my_func()` isn't finished yet? BTW I added additional info in my question.

Comment: I dont think it should. Test it out though, cant myself right now. To test it put a time() at the end of your function (within it) and compare $after to that time, they should be the same or really close.